# Does building a binary using Expo compress the size of an application?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, binaryfiles

I'm getting ready to deploy my react native application to the iOS App Store, and am going to build a binary using expo (something I've never done before). However, something that has confused me since I started this project is why my application folder is so big. My app has maybe around 40 images, most smaller than a few hundred kb. However, the node_modules folder is pretty large and makes up the bulk of my application folder with about 150mb of packages, most of which I don't use and the ones I do using only contributing to a fraction of that total. When I build a binary, will those unused packages be included in the binary or will it be much smaller than it is right now? If it will still be around the same size after building, how can I significantly shrink the size of my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it will not be included in the bundle. In my experience, a basic React Native app is roughly 7-11MB. Yours will of course be larger if you have a ton of components and static assets, but it's nothing to worry about.